# How to plot this equation for $x,y$?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

```
(1 + r^2 + x)^2 - (-1 + r)^2 ((1 + x)^2 + y^2)=0

2 (2 r^3 + (1 + x)^2 + y^2 - r (-1 + x^2 + y^2))=0
```

I am trying to plot $x$ and $y$ which are giving by the equations above so what I did is that I solve the second equation for $c$ then substituted the value of $c$ in the first equation and then used the `ContourPlot` function to plot $x$ and $y$. The problem is that when solving for $c$ in the second equation we get three solutions and each one results in a different plot when substituted in the first equation. Also, there seems to be some disconnect at some areas. Why is this happening and is there a way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `Eliminate[]` to get rid of `c` from the system of equations?

Comment: By the way, people here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2, I have just tried `Eliminate` and it seems that it does work but what in the case of a more complicated equations when you need to solve for $c$?

Comment: Do you have such an example? There are going to be uncomputable problems due to the finite limitations of the hardware and software. But have some doubt that there is a pair of polynomials for which you could solve for `c` but not eliminate it. That's just intuition and I could be wrong. It's also possible that computing `Eliminate[]` takes much more time, so that it cannot effectively be done.

Comment: There's no `c` in your equations. I guess you meant `r`.

Answer (score 4):

```
soln = {x, y} /. Solve[{
      (1 + r^2 + x)^2 - (-1 + r)^2 ((1 + x)^2 + y^2) == 0,
      2 (2 r^3 + (1 + x)^2 + y^2 - r (-1 + x^2 + y^2)) == 0},
     {x, y}, Reals] // Normal // Simplify

(*  {{-1 - 2*r + r^2, 
     -Sqrt[(-(-4 + r))*r^3]}, 
   {-1 - 2*r + r^2, 
     Sqrt[(-(-4 + r))*r^3]}}  *)

ParametricPlot[Evaluate@soln, {r, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
eq = {(1 + r^2 + x)^2 - (-1 + r)^2 ((1 + x)^2 + y^2) == 0, 
    2 (2 r^3 + (1 + x)^2 + y^2 - r (-1 + x^2 + y^2)) == 0};

el = Eliminate[eq, r]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate @ el, {x, -3, 7}, {y, -6, 6}]
```

[image]